# Pyramid server port in environment variable or argument to pserve

Tags: python, pyramid

I want to specify the server port for pyramid (using default pserve) through an environment variable or as a command line argument. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command `pserve --help` tells us:

> Usage: pserve-script.py config_uri [start|stop|restart|status] [var=value]
>
> This command serves a web application that uses a PasteDeploy
>   configuration file for the server and application.  If
>   start/stop/restart is given, then
>   --daemon is implied, and it will start (normal operation), stop (--stop- daemon), or do both.  **You can also include variable
>   assignments like 'http_port=8080' and then use %(http_port)s in your
>   config files.**

So, for example:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 127.0.0.1
port = %(http_port)s
```

and run `pserve mydevapp.ini http_port=1234`

Comment: awesome, is there a way to have a default value?

Comment: There is not possible to have a default value. This is known limitation of paste.deploy:
https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastedeploy/issue/7/values-in-default-section-override-those

Comment: It appears that a fix for this was [merged](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastedeploy/pull-requests/7/allow-global_conf-to-override-defaults-see/activity) 2016-03-09, but no release is including it yet.